I’m confused by how the term “syntactic marker” is used in CGEL
I am confused about the term syntactic marker as
used in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL),
by Huddleston and Pullum.
They say that to, for, that, but, and, nor, either,
neither etc. are “markers”. But they also say that ‑s,
‑es, ‑ed, ‑ing are “markers”, as well.
But I don’t understand why those are called syntactic
markers. How many different types of these “markers”
does English possess?
Can you please give me a clear explanation on this
topic?

Does this answer your question?

@tchrist I meant how conjunctions and prepositions are synthetic markers. What actually do markers in sentences?

@tchrist: I'd like to vtc for "lack of research" because it's well covered by Wikipedia, but that's not dictionaries. Is there an approved route for my vtc, or should I not be trying to close it anyway? It doesn't look like an ELL question to me. Is it a question for SO Linguistics?

Tell us where you read this stuff, what it said, and what your problem is.

@StuartF For example, I know that he is right. Here why that is called a marker? Are markers used to only marks something?

I am trying to understand the syntactic marker of the book CGEL of huddleston & pullum.

@Salimuddin I remain unclear what you mean here. When you say "synthetic markers", do you mean grammatical markers used in synthetic languages rather than in analytic languages? Bound morphemes used to produce reflexes of a word are frequent in synthetic languages, those with higher morpheme-to-word ratios. Free morphemes like conjunctions and prepositions are common in analytic languages, those with lower morpheme-to-word ratios. Many languages use both kinds of marker to a greater or lesser extent, including English.

@tchrist Yes, I mean syntactic language. I have got it in CGEL (Huddleston & pullum). For example, "I know what you need" Here is "what" functioning as both the Object of the sub-clause and the synthetic marker in the whole sentence?

English always has alternatives. I know your need could carry the same "multifaceted" functionality just by turning you into your

@Salimuddin What you need remains unclear to me. Are you looking for information on the grammatical role of wh-clauses (sometimes called embedded questions or indirect questions) within the surrounding grammatical structure?

Why are you reading that book? It's incredibly complex for inexpert native speakers  to even understand. By the number of errors in your post, and in the comments, your English level is at best intermediate-plus. Choose something easier to improve your knowledge of grammar.

Just quote the chapter and the page number from CGEL, there are users on EL&U who practically know it by heart and read it before going to bed.

@Mari-LouA Cause I need to know the appropriate syntax. What should I do now? Can you recommend me any books or anything?

Now the edit makes you appear a proficient speaker... (smh) Anyway, please quote the page number(s).

@Mari-LouA In CGEL, the chapter: 11, the page number: 956 & the topic: Whether

I don't understand what you mean by the topic. Do mean the title of the chapter or the subheading? As it is, "Whether" seems quite unlikely.

I mean in this topic, there are 3 examples where that, whether & what help is said as markers.  But as well what help is the  object of the sub-clause.  And 'that' & 'whether' are functioning only as the marker. It's making me confused.

CGEL is, objectively speaking, a difficult book and if your English isn't at a native speaker level (C2) you shouldn't be tackling it. But if you must, then choose a high-quality software programme that will translate excerpts in your mother tongue. You will probably then have a better grasp of the information.

I don't have time to look it up but I'm 99.999% certain that they don't say that "‑s, ‑es, ‑ed, ‑ing " are syntactic markers. They aren't syntactic in any way.

@Salimuddin 'Marker' is a syntactic function. For example "that" is a pronoun that functions as a marker of subordination in declarative clauses. And "whether" is a subordinator whose function is that of marker of subordination in interrogative clauses. Markers are semantically empty.

In the proverbial 25 words or less, a marker is a chunk of articulated sound that indicates a particular kind of grammatical function but is otherwise devoid of meaning.
For example:

-ed is the past tense marker for regular verbs
that is a marker indicating that what ensues is a subordinate clause
the ending s marks the third person present singular form of the verb


"I know what you have."  Here is what both the Object of sub-clause and the marker function of the sentence?

@Salimuddin I don't think CGEL claims that "what" is a marker in a sentence like that.

@TimR Isn't 'what' the conjunction and introducing the sub-clause?

@Lambie And one thing is wheather the function 'marker' is equal to subject, Object, complement, modifer or not? If so, then what are its positions?

@lambie and Salim You should not take "I amble"'s comment seriously as none of the words you mentioned in your question is a preposition (although some are homophonous with them, for example 'to' and 'for')..

@Araucaria-Him then can you tell me what exactly markers are? What do markers do in sentences?

@Salimuddin According to H&P, what is not a conjunction.

@Lambie "to" is also the infinitive marker. It happens to be a homogram of a preposition as well, but that may not be the sense CGEL is referring to.

@Lambie CGEL is talking about the uses of to and for found in "They called for him to resign."

@alphabet CGEL wouldn't treat for as a sort of "particle" (or whatever term wouldn't send them into conniptions) accompanying certain verbs that express will or desire? (call, yearn, wish, vote, opt, shout, yell, etc)?  Does CGEL ever delve into comparative Germanic or comparative Indo-European constructions?

Alphabet is right. CGEL sensibly classifies "for" and "to" as subordinators functioning as markers. The former is a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses, while the latter is a marker of to infinitivals that contain a subject.


Syntactic markers are serial graphemic elements that indicate syntactic features. These features create coherence within phrases and between words or word groups on the clause level. Syntactic features are, therefore, not word-related but link larger entities of a sentence. In many languages, syntactic features are identical with inflection affixes. An example of this is conjugation: In English, the 3rd person singular is marked syntactically, distinguishing (I/you/we…) sing and (s/he) sings. In French, conjugation more strongly differentiates between the markers of person. However, only the 1st and 2nd person plural are phonologically transparent. All other persons differ in spelling but not phonologically (cf. for the verb to sing the 1st and 2nd person plural compared to all other grammatical persons: [ʃɑ̃te], [ʃɑ̃tɔ̃], [ʃɑ̃t]).
Another example is the nominal plural  in English: Pronounced [s], as in cats [kεts], the marker is phonologically transparent. Confusion might arise, however, between the ending of the (one-morpheme) word fox [fɔks] and the (two-morpheme) word socks [sɔks]. Moreover, plural  can be articulated as [s] or [z], depending on the previously articulated phonemes.
Neither all syntactic features, nor all markers, indicate inflection. Some mark a particular word class. The  spelling in whether, for instance, highlights the interrogative pronoun in the paradigm of what, when, etc., and is therefore a syntactic marker. The homophone weather, in contrast, does not include any syntactic features.
Distinguishing Syntactic Markers From Morphological Markers. A Cross-Linguistic Comparison
author: Constanze Weth

This is a community-wiki post, users are free to edit the post as they wish.

I've had to downvote this because the quoted bit doesn't match what is usually meant by 'syntactic marker' at all, and in particular in CGEL. Most specifically, syntactic markers are not 'graphemic'. Thy have nothing to do with writing at all. Most of the worlds languages have 'markers'. Many of the those languages have no graphemic system whatsoever!!

@Araucaria-Him  I think the professor is saying that syntactic markers are identifiable in writing, not that they are graphemes per se. In any case, the answer was intended as a springboard, if I had access to the CGEL, I might have paraphrased the paragraphs that were confusing the OP. BTW, the OP says it's Chapter 11, p986. I know several users keep a copy on their bedside table, judging by the number of times they reference it :)
